# How to display custom fields from Leads and Contact on a activities report?

Tags: contact, leads, activities

Goal: I'm trying to create an activities (Tasks and Events) report that will display custom fields from the Lead object, and a standard field (MailingAddress) from the Contact object. I will need all of these to display on the Activities object without duping the information onto the activities.

Any suggestions?

Comment: should your report be exportable into excel? if not you can build a joined report in salesforce

Comment: So let me add more content to this question . I am working on a project with Conga. I need a report's data to be task and events that show the lead / contacts address associated to that activity. Joined reports are not support by Conga.

Comment: Awesome, if you already are using conga it should be a breeezee, I love conga. Build 2 reports 1) Activities with Lead 2) Activities with Contacts and then export both to excel and vlookup the finally summary based on activity Id

Comment: I originally was going to build it out this way, but I wanted to only have one report. So far the only way I can find this possible, is to write out some apex code that will grab the corresponding address fields that would be selected based on the whoId of activity. Unfortunately this would dupe data by taking those address fields and basically copying them to my new custom fields on Activities. This Reporting will be used daily that is going to be automated by Conductor, so I do not want to do any exporting.